# Is there a Microsoft alternative to WSUS other than SCCM?

Tags: wsus, windows-server-2019

WSUS 2016 "allows" 3rd party patches through APIs, but it is buggy. Is there another free alternative built in to say Windows Server 2019?

Comment: WSUS is an update management system. SCCM is a systems management system which includes the ability to manage updates. Why would Microsoft create yet another solution?

Comment: Group Policy has functionality to deploy and update software, but when we experimented with it (decades ago) we found it unreliable.  Don't know if it has improved at all in the meantime.  You can also use startup scripts, though that means building all the actual deployment logic yourself which is pretty clunky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCCM isn't an alternative to WSUS.  It simply adds an orchestration layer on top.  It's still WSUS under the hood.

Since MSFT already makes SCCM and WSUS any other service offering would be in competition and that's generally not allowed at MSFT.

However, you can look at third party offerings like Novell ZENworks or build your own.